# Cannot able to build solution for iOS when i use CrossMedia.Current.Initialize(); using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I used `CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();` method to select photo from gallery and it's perfectly working for android but when i try to build the solution for iOS it's getting an error

```
Failed to compile the generated registrar code. Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com MyProject.iOS
```

But when i comment `CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();` code it's perfectly working fine.

i am not able to identify where was the issue. So can anyone help me out from this issue?

Comment: The fact that error message is from `mtouch` dating Oct 4, 2018 (or before), I would recommend that you update your version of `Xamarin.iOS`.

Comment: Thanks @Sushi, how can i update it?

Comment: Not knowing if you are using just macOS or Windows&macOS, .... try https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/xamarin/

Comment: But this link is for to install xamarin with visual studio and i already have visual studio 2017 with updated v15.9.16.

Comment: Check what version of Xamarin.iOS do you have on your system?

Comment: @ManishTiwari Hi , you can have a try with the latest version of Visual Studio 2019. Recently , apple release the  IOS 13 , there will maybe something not match old version , even in CrossMedia or vs .

Answer (score 0):

Have a check in IOS whether add [permissions in Info.Plist](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#ios) :

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the camera to take photos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to photos.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to microphone.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the photo gallery.</string>
```

By the way , you'd better update VS 2017 to VS 2019 version.

My local project works well .Its version is *Visual Studio 2019 16.3.1* , *Xamarin Forms is 4.2.0.815419* and *Xam.Plugin.Media is 4.0.1.5*.